# is Android key for maps similar to youtube key?

Tags: android, youtube, maps, key

I am using google maps and youtube in one application, so they need two keys. 
Can I generate one key fot both of them?
I can create a project in google console then create a new client id then create an Android key. Does it work for both maps and youtube?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer to your question is no.. You can not generate one key fot both of them. Sad truth, i know. In the future this may become possible as Youtube is owned my Google now.

Comment: What I am doing in the google console is: going to 'services', turn on the youtube and google maps , then going to 'api access' and generating a key with SHA1 and package name, so to who does it belong? maps or youtube?

Comment: Can you help me to build a youtube key.